# Visualforce building

Tags: visualforce, metadata

I would like to develop a vf page, which displays three columns from one object.

Field Name | Help Text | Description of the fields.

I would like to capture these above mentioned details in a visualforce page.
 Kindly help. I tried the below code and it does not suit my requirement

```
 <apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection > 
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.Active__c.inlineHelpText}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Active__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection> 
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

basically we have 600 custom fields on account object. Now, i need to identify, the list of fields which do not have help text and description. I saw "field trip app salesforce" but i cannot install that to our org. So, am building a vf page which displays list of all the fields along with help text and description. Can you please guide me on that ?

Comment: <apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection > 
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.Active__c.inlineHelpText}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Active__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection> 
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>

Comment: What error are you facing error?

Comment: Hi Tushar, I can do this for only one field. Requirement is for account object, i need to display all the field names, help text for the fields and its respective description. Like Field Names | Help Text | Description.

Comment: For the help text when you use inputfield  you also get help text .you don't need to do anything extra.

Comment: ok, basically we have 600 custom fields on account object. Now, i need to identify, the list of fields which do not have help text and description. I saw "field trip app salesforce" but i cannot install that to our org. So, am building a vf page which displays list of all the fields along with help text and description. Can you please guide me on that ? By this - i can identify right ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fMap = Account.getDescribe().Fields.getMap();
list<string> selectFields = new list<string>();

for (Schema.SObjectField ft : fMap.values()){ // loop through all field tokens 
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fd = ft.getDescribe(); // describe each field
    system.debug(fd.getLabel());
    system.debug(fd.getInlineHelpText()); // Inline text
}
```

Refer all other details about a field
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm

However there are no direct ways to access Description information. You can only query them by accessing Metadata apis. Below are the references you can start with

http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/10/27/introduction-to-calling-the-metadata-api-from-apex/

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/api_meta.pdf

> Updated Code

```
<apex:page controller="FieldDescriberController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection > 
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!fieldHelpTextMap}" var="field">
                    <apex:column value="{!field}" headerValue="FieldName"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!fieldHelpTextMap[field]}" headerValue="FieldHelpText"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection> 
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
Public Class FieldDescriberController{

    Public Map<String,String> fieldHelpTextMap {get;set;}

    Public FieldDescriberController(){
        fieldHelpTextMap = new Map<String,String>();
        populateFields();
    }

    Public void populateFields(){

        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fMap = Account.getsObjectType().getDescribe().Fields.getMap();
        list<string> selectFields = new list<string>();

        for (Schema.SObjectField ft : fMap.values()){ // loop through all field tokens 
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult fd = ft.getDescribe(); // describe each field
            if(!String.isBlank(fd.getInlineHelpText()))
                fieldHelpTextMap.put(fd.getLabel(),fd.getInlineHelpText());
            else
                fieldHelpTextMap.put(fd.getLabel(),'');

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Salesforcesmarty, Thanks for the help, can you please help me in mapping the code to the VF page ?. Just sample would do be helpful .

Comment: Hi Salefsforcesmarty, Your code works perfect...Thanks a lot for the inputs of the resources. I will check all those..

Answer (score 0):

Use Extensions="(ApexClassName)" keyword in apex:page tag

In that Apex class, use the SOQL Query to get the required fields and call that result in VF Page.

Comment: Hi Subhash, Please let me know from where i can query Field Names | Help Text | Description

Comment: what do you want?
field name (label) or that particular field value?

Comment: yes i want field label, help text and description - which we key in while creating the field...                                                                               basically we have 600 custom fields on account object. Now, i need to identify, the list of fields which do not have help text and description. I saw "field trip app salesforce" but i cannot install that to our org. So, am building a vf page which displays list of all the fields along with help text and description

Answer (score 0):

You can try one thing. Take your Object and field backup in Eclipse IDE.  Now in your Eclipse open the meta XML file of Account Object and you can check the help text and description. Also you can modify it from there if you want to make any change in help text or description just change value and then save it. It is not exact solution but will help you lot.

Answer (score 0):

That should have been easy! Although I don't like posting full codes in Answers. I recommend you to read the links provided by @Salesforcesmarty, they would help you understand the logic better.

Create a class to use as Extension in the page.

```
public class MyExtension{
        public List<List<String>> fieldDetails{get;set;} //Could have used a wrapper class, but this will serve your purpose.
        public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController std){
        fieldDetails = new List<List<String>>();
        Map <String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fMap = schemaMap.get('Account').getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        list<string> selectFields = new list<string>();
        for (Schema.SObjectField ft : fMap.values()){ // loop through all field tokens 
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult fd = ft.getDescribe(); // describe each field
        fieldDetails.add(new List<String>{fd.getLabel(), fd.getInlineHelpText()}); //unfortunately, there is no direct method I could find to fetch the description of the field.
        }
        }
        }
```

Add the extension in your page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="MyExtension">
```

and loop through the list of list of strings.

```
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!fieldDetails}" var="field">
    <apex:repeat value="{!field}" var="textToDisplay">
    <apex:column>
      <apex:outputText value="{!textToDisplay}"/>
    </apex:column>
    </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks Santanu... Your code solved my problem.. I will check for description as well and post if I find any..

Comment: No problem mate! Good luck!